# Textbox losing focus after cursor selection moved to end

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a form that loads, hits a button (to add text to a textbox), moves the cursor to the end of the textbox text, and then sets the active control to the textbox, so the user can immediately start typing. The textbox is populated fine, but the form loses its focus. This is only with the selection line in there, if I take it out, it works fine. The user has to click on the form to make it active. Any ideas?

```
private void createNewFolder_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     addDate.PerformClick();
     folderNameTextBox.Select(folderNameTextBox.Text.Length, 0);
     this.ActiveControl = folderNameTextBox;
     this.Focus();
}
```

Comment: his.ActiveControl = folderNameTextBox;
 is fine, you need to remove this.Focus(); and change it to folderNameTextBox.Focus();

Comment: ikathegreat, this.Focus looks like it refers to the Form itself and not the active control.. does this make sense.. pardon the pun on "this",,

Comment: maybe that detail was not entirely obvious, but this is a new dialog window that appears and the code above is for the formload event. by clicking on the form after it's loaded, the textbox HAS focus. i don't have to click in it, so i need to make this form active somehow i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing cannot work in the Load event, the form is not yet visible.  By far the simplest way is to just give the control the lowest TabIndex.  Or use the Select() method:

```
private void createNewFolder_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    addDate.PerformClick();
    folderNameTextBox.Select(folderNameTextBox.Text.Length, 0);
    folderNameTextBox.Select();
}
```

Comment: +1 Completely agree. Indeed, Focus is used too much (and according to M$ is really for control writing internally and Select(), which does the focus thing anyway, is the preferred method).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
this.ActiveControl = folderNameTextBox;
```

Try:

```
folderNameTextBox.Focus();
```

If the textbox is still out of focus, try selecting it using:

```
folderNameTextBox.Select();
```